# I want to send and receive data wirelessly from 90 different areas to a central collection site. longest distance is 8.5 miles.

Tags: wireless, communication, data

I have 90 pump/lift stations that I would like to send information from to a central collection place (office).  The longest distance is 8.5 miles away.  most of these pump stations are line of sight over a lake.  What is the least expensive way to turn these old stations into a station that can send digital information wirelessly.  We would also need a server? to collect this data.

Comment: How much data, how often?

Comment: I am unsure of how much data it would take.  Daily I would like it to send data if a breaker has been tripped, running amps, hours pumps have run.  And ideal if I could request to receive that data on demand.

Comment: Is it bi-directional data? Is it control commands or just monitoring information for collection? What are your country's rules and regs on ISM bands?

Comment: bi-directional data would be nice but most importantly would be monitoring info. for collection.  I don't know what the frequency requirements are for my state or country.  This is for Utah, United States

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use [long-range Wi-Fi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-range_Wi-Fi).  You want to use 5.8 GHz 802.1n, since that has twice the range of the more common 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi right of the bat.

You should put a omnidirectional antenna at your main location [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NQGVZGS) which has a gain of 12dBi:

[image]

and directional antennas at your pump/lift stations [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IVJ1LR8), which has a gain of 30dBi:

[image]

Since Wi-Fi routers are designed to work with local LANs which have 255 maximum devices (the lowest octet of an IP address), handling 90 devices should not be a problem, except I would set it up so that the communication from the pump/lift stations is staggered so they don't compete.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with something like Akiba's/Freaklab's open-source wireless stuff:  http://www.freaklabsstore.com/

We would need to know somewhat more about your needs to make any solid recommendations on high level architecture...